# A word meaning "able to be muted"

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "mutable" means changeable, rather than "able to be muted". Is there a word that carries this meaning?

Comment: Perhaps silenceable?

Comment: @RK01 silenceable isn't in any dictionaries, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 It is used in writing, although not put into a dictionary. That's why I put it in as a comment.

Comment: @RK01 Oh. I'd agree with you on it though, I had thought of it too, but since I couldn't find it and you had already said it, I didn't answer with it.

Comment: Is there a particular context you are wanting to use this in? I'm having a hard time thinking of a counter example wherein you are unable to mute something that can typically be muted.

Comment: Quietable may also work, although it falls under the same category as silenceable.

Comment: If you want to avoid "mutable" (which would probably be understood in context, btw) how about something like "audio-optional"?

Comment: @Etheur Ever been in a store in which the management thinks it's a good idea to have TV monitors blasting commercials shilling for their products?  Sometimes I can find the volume button to mute the damn things, and sometimes I can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is ***muteable***. It is an uncommon word and not listed in credible dictionaries but it is in *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muteable)*:

> Capable of being muted.

Comment: "... not listed in credible dictionaries" also applies to **quietable** and **silenceable** if the OP wants more options.

Comment: @Blubberguy22: Well, it is self-explanatory. "Quietable" and "silenceable" might have different connotations but OP didn't give a clear context. I assume it is related to sound.

Comment: I'll go with this, since it seems the least likely to confuse a reader.

Comment: Neither @FatherLuke 's hyphenated version nor this unhyphenated version registers at all on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=muteable%2Cmute-able&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: Many homophones have more than one meaning.  Muteable if you must, but *mutable* gets my vote.

Comment: @Dan and yet we spell changeable with 2 e's...interestingly enough "muteable" would have the definition of "changeable" in the context of computer science but would mean "able to be silenced" in the context of user-interface design, a subset of computer science.

Comment: @DaveKaye In Computer Science, the word you are talking about is (almost) always spelled "mutable" without the 'e'.

Comment: Yes, guess I got ginned up by my own example.

Answer (score 1):

Try: mute-able.

Hyphenating allows the two to act as a single idea. This is called a **compound adjective**.

Answer (score -1):

From the OED:

> [mutable](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124284), adj.
>
> 1. b.  *Grammar and Phonetics.* Of a consonant sound: subject to mutation ([see mutation n. 5](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124296#eid35611883)). **Now rare**.

Comment: Reason for the downvote? This is actually a word, abeit it is rarely used like this.

Comment: The question asks for a word to describe something that can be *muted*, not *mutated*, and specifically rules out *mutable*.

Comment: @choster the word mutable also means what the OP intends, although it is **"now rare"ly** used as such. I answered like this because the OP didn't know that the word "mutable" has such a meaning, which is why it was ruled out in the first place.

Comment: I did not in fact know that. Thanks.

Comment: @prosd It is probably a bad idea to use it though, since it is rare. I'd go with ermanen, even though it lacks "credible dictionaries."

Comment: This is in the context of phonetics. You didn't include "Grammar and Phonetics" part from OED.

Comment: @ermanen oops, but what I intended still holds true; that the word mutable still has a meaning somewhat similar to what the OP thought wasn't something. I fixed it; thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: *Mutation* in sense n. 5 in OED is still *change;* it does not correspond to the action of the Mute button on your TV remote, or the action of the brass or string player's *sordino.*